# Filesystem of Windows Phone?

Tags: operating-system, filesystems, windows-phone

What is the name of filesystem in Windows Phone OS?

I am aware of `Isolated Storage`, but is it the name given to the file system OR does it constitute a full-fledged filesystem, such as; exFat, NTFS or ReFS?

Comment: I don't think this has ever been announced. I'm curious why you need to know this though?

Answer (score 4):

Isolated Storage is just an abstraction. Windows Phone 7 used Windows CE as the backend, and Windows CE uses its own storage management mechanisms. CE also supports FAT (I don't remember the exact flavor) for external memory. Windows Phone 8 *probably* uses NTFS but this is just a guess.